# Source of the Napoleon "God/Devil/immortal" quote

Tags: quotes, sources, napoleon

I heard in a history lecture (I don't know who the lecturer was) the following quote about Napoleon:

> Some say he's God (an angel?), some say he's the Devil, but everyone agrees he
>   isn't mortal.

The above is not necessarily the exact words of the quote – it might have been simpler, e.g. "He was either God or the Devil, but definitely not mortal", or it might have used the word "man" instead of mortal. The exact words are immaterial, but the point was that it was discussing Napoleon's goodness and greatness – he was either very good or very bad but he was certainly exceptionally great. The contrast was made using the terminology of humans and divine beings.

I am wondering if anyone has heard such a quote before. I have not been able to find it written anywhere. Does anyone have a historical source for this?

(It is of course possible that the lecturer made it up).

Comment: Unless you can provide an exact quote, I'd say this is unanswerable. I could find both quotes depicting him as a hellspawn and demigod, but none implying Napoleon is immortal. On another hand, you might find [this article](http://eprints.lse.ac.uk/29371/1/Imposing%20on%20Napoleon%20the%20Romantic%20appropriation%20of%20Bonaparte%20%28LSERO%29.pdf) interesting. It discusses the representation of Bonaparte in British Romantic literature, and some ideas there are along the lines of this phrase.

Comment: @AaronBrick Now that I think about it, it might have been "angel" instead if God.

Comment: Did you read the quote in English? Or are you translating it? More generally, in which context did you hear the sentence?

Comment: @Taladris I didn't read it anywhere. I heard it in a history lecture. I'm looking for a written source.

Comment: Maybe you should mention what lecture it was from then, as this seems unlikely to be a verbatim quote of any written source.

Comment: @Semaphore I don't know what lecture it was from.

Answer (score 16):

Napoleon is widely described as either a demigod or a demon / devil, though, as Danila Smirnov mentioned, *not* immortal. Might you be misremembering this, or perhaps something like it:

> Napoleon . . . [is]  **sometimes cast as a demigod, sometimes as a demon**, practically always seen as **a figure considerably larger than life.** Probably no other **mortal** has received so much attention from historians and biographers, critics and enthusiasts.
>
> <sub>Herold, J. Christopher. *The Horizon Book of the Age of Napoleon*. Harmony, 1983.</sub>

The "no other mortal" phrase that followed could well have caused a confusion in the memory.

---

On the note of angels; it's a different Napoleon, but [Samuel Schmucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Mosheim_Schmucker) offered this formulation:

> Louis Napoleon is neither on the one hand an idiot or a demon; nor is he on the other a demigod or an **angel**.
>
> <sub>*The Public and Private History of Napoleon the Third*, 1858</sub>

Comment: No, the point was that everyone related to him with a sense of greatness. If you liked him he was an angel/God, if you hated him he was the Devil but all would agree that he was no regular human.

Comment: @Alex Obviously I understand the underlying meaning, that's why I suggested "figure larger than life" to be the answer - does it not mean precisely "he was no regular human"?.

Comment: Okay, perhaps the basic meaning is the same. I was thinking of a stronger statement, though.

Comment: @Alex Well then, given you're looking for hearsay with no evidence it even came from print, this is likely to be an unanswerable case of No True Scotsman.

Comment: It's not a No True Scotsman because I'm not changing any parameters based on someone's examples. I'm just saying that the quote that I'm referring to was much more explicit.

Comment: Indeed I am remembering hearing this somewhere. My question was if anyone knows a source that actually says this.

Comment: @Alex My point is the quote might not have any real source at all, being merely the lecturer's expression in the moment. Or it might be based on something real, but your memory is apparently inaccurate, else a straightforward search would have found it. As such you should supply as much information as you can of *where and how you heard it* - you said a lecture, which? Otherwise it's just a wild goose chase and, yes, No True Scotsman: you have gone from "something expressing this idea" to "...but *more explicit*".

Comment: When I said "something expressing this idea" I did not intend some vague, hazy concept. I simply meant that I do not have the exact words of the quote. What I do remember is the explicit contrast between good Divine beings, bad Divine beings, and human beings. I have edited the question to make this clear.